# Soundmanager2: how to know if a sound played successfully?

Tags: javascript, html, soundmanager2

How can I find out if a sound played successfully, and put code to handle an error?

```
s1 = soundManager.createSound({url:'http://www.example.com/sound1.mp3'});
s1.play();
```

I am concerned that there is a connectivity issue, or the file is not found or size zero. Is there an exception I can catch, or event raised?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you create a sound, it is possible to assign callbacks to some events. In the [docs](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/) you can find further explanation. To add callbacks to your object write your createSound function like this:

```
    s1 = soundManager.createSound({
      url: 'http://www.example.com/sound1.mp3',
      onconnect: function() { 
        // Fired when the file can be played and the connection is created
      },
      onload: function() { 
        // Fired when the file is completely loaded by the client
      },
      ondataerror: function() {
        // Fired when there is a Flash error
      },
      onfinish: function() {
        // Fired when the file has been completely reproduced
      }
   });

   s1.play();
```

The **onconnect** callback is a way to detect that the file can be played before calling the play() method which will not rise visible error. **ondataerror** it's going to tell you when any error occurs during playback of your audio file.

Comment: Thanks the the answer! How might I know if the file has definitely been played successfully? Seems from these events I can only find if there has been a play error?

Comment: I updated the answer with the `onfinish: function()` callback that fires just when the file was completely reproduced.